# sparklyr spark_apply is very slow

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr

sparklyr spark_apply is very slow / not responding at all. When checking in spark UI , the stage which is executing is collect at utils.scala:204. It is executing 0/1(1 running) tasks. The data frame on which the spark_apply is applied has 30 partitions. There is no progress in this task and why a single task is being executed

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
config=spark_config()
config=c(config, list("spark.files"="hdfs:///bundle/packages.tar","spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"="false","spark.executor.memory"="10g","spark.executor.cores"="4","spark.executor.instances"="7"))
sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn", app_name = "demo",config = config,version="2.3.0")
demo_data <- spark_read_csv(sc,name='demo_data',path = '/data.txt',delimiter = '\t',infer_schema = FALSE, columns = list(column1 = "integer"))
spark_apply(demo_data, function(df) df * 10, packages = "packages.tar" ,columns=list(column1="integer"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My trick is to run a minimal spark_apply function (from [rstudio.com](https://spark.rstudio.com/guides/distributed-r/)) just after cluster initialization: `spark_apply(function(e) I(e))` for the R environment to be initialized on each node from start.

In is book "mastering spark with R" 
javier luraschi recommands using spark_apply [as a last resort](https://therinspark.com/distributed.html), even if the [following explainations](https://therinspark.com/distributed.html#functions), show that a lot as been invested to overcome the bottleneck, in particular the development of the arrow library.

Maybe at this point should he mention more appropriates ways (see [Spark and Sparklyr](https://teachdatascience.com/parallel/) ) to run parallel task using sparklyr.

On github he explains that spark_apply suffer a serialization issue as explained [here](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/1457) and [here](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/980#issuecomment-328922215)

On the other hand, [randomgambit](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/980#issuecomment-329513634) believes that the prerformance issue is rather due to the Sparklyr behaviour that is copying the entire R distribution over each node.

In my case, the problem is not appenning in local mode, 
but during the first execution of spark_apply in cluster mode:

Using the test command from [rstudio.com](https://spark.rstudio.com/guides/distributed-r/) 
the benchmark gives the following performance to run this expression

```
sdf_len(sc, 5, repartition = 1) %>% spark_apply(function(e) I(e))
```

- local mode:

  `Unit: seconds
  min      lq       mean     median    uq       max      neval
  5.043947 5.043947 5.043947 5.043947  5.043947 5.043947     1`
- cluster mode (one master, one worker):

  - first execution

  `Unit: seconds
  min      lq       mean     median   uq       max      neval
  928.0637 928.0637 928.0637 928.0637 928.0637 928.0637     1`

  - second execution

  `Unit: seconds
  min      lq       mean     median   uq       max      neval 
  4.309775 4.309775 4.309775 4.309775 4.309775 4.309775     1`

Given that the second execution is much faster, I believe that the 923 seconds = **15 minutes, 23 seconds** are required for Sparklyr to copy the entire R distribution on each node.

Here is the code used:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(sparklyr) 
library(microbenchmark)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

microbenchmark(
  sdf_len(sc, 5, repartition = 1) %>% spark_apply(function(e) I(e))
  ,times = 1L)    

conf <- spark_config()
conf[["spark.r.command"]] <- "d:/path_to/R-3.6.1/bin/Rscript.exe"
sc <- spark_connect(master="spark://192.168.0.12:7077", 
                                        version = "2.4.3",
                                        spark_home = "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\spark\\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7",
                                        config = conf)
microbenchmark(
  sdf_len(sc, 5, repartition = 1) %>% spark_apply(function(e) I(e))
  ,times = 1L)
microbenchmark(
  sdf_len(sc, 5, repartition = 1) %>% spark_apply(function(e) I(e))
  ,times = 1L)
```

Comment: same with spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: In fact, spark_apply should only be used if you can't convert your R code into dplyr's syntax, in wich case, your code should be converted into spark routines by sparklyr. On the contrary, spark_apply starts a full R environement on spark nodes.